# Select query returning all table data and not processing the where clause

Tags: mysql

Table(`TBL_Details`) stores following  `CartID`
, `ProductID`, and a quantity of products.
Table(`TBL_Product`) stores product information, such as: name and price.

I am having trouble as the where clause is not limiting the data being displayed and it is showing the sum of all the items in the table.

I have tried changing the where clause, but no luck.

> SELECT SUM(`Price`) AS 'Total Price' FROM `TBL_Details`, `TBL_Product`
>   WHERE `CartID` = 1;

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

> SELECT SUM(`Price`) AS 'Total Price' FROM `TBL_Details`, `TBL_Product`
>   WHERE `CartID` = 1;
>
> Total Price: 200

Comment: so you need the sum of the price depends on the cart Id?

Comment: You could use group by with having.

Comment: Yes, price coming from table product and cartID coming from table details which has the productID stored; it being a foreign key from the product table.

Comment: How would I implement that, I apologise I am new to mysql.

Comment: @Kingwebbie001 You should `join` and apply `group by` in the query. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `join` and apply `group by` in the query

```sql
SELECT *, SUM(TBL_Product.price) as totalPrice
FROM TBL_Details 
LEFT JOIN TBL_Product ON TBL_Product.id = TBL_Details.ProductID
GROUP BY TBL_Details.CartID
```

Comment: This also worked, thank you so much; it's good to have an alternative method!

Answer (score 1):

assuming `TBL_Product` contains ProductID aswell:

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS 'Total Price' 
FROM TBL_Details JOIN TBL_Product ON TBL_Product.ProductID=TBL_Details.ProductID
WHERE CartID = 1;
```

should output the sum of all products within cartID 1.
correct me if im wrong

Comment: no problem. feel free to upvote the solutions that helped you

Answer (score 0):

based on what I can deduce. you would need to link the 2 tables together first with an ID.

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS 'Total Price' FROM TBL_Details a, TBL_Product b WHERE 
a.ProductID = b.ProductID AND
CartID = 1;
```